# Why const by-value structural binding allows the user to modify referenced variable?

Tags: c++, c++17

I am rather confused with structural binding. Even if I use `const` and by-value (without `&`) structural binding as in this example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

int main()
{
    int x = 0;
    std::tuple<int&> p(x);
    const auto [a] = p;
    a++;
    std::cout << x << '\n';
}
```

It still modifies `x` and prints `1`: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/jc8hxE8M6

Could you please explain why it works that way and want changes if I add `&` before `[a]` or remove `const`?

Comment: `const auto` isn't qualifying `a`, it's qualifying the anonymous temporary copy of `p`. Modifying `a` (or consequently `x`) doesn't modify the anonymous temporary copy, because it doesn't own `x`, it merely holds it by reference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the example on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding):

> The portion of the declaration preceding `[` applies to the hidden
> variable e, not to the introduced identifiers.
>
> ```
> int a = 1, b = 2;
> const auto& [x, y] = std::tie(a, b); // x and y are of type int&
> auto [z, w] = std::tie(a, b);        // z and w are still of type int&
> assert(&z == &a);                    // passes
> ```

Where `e` refers to

> A structured binding declaration first introduces a uniquely-named variable (here denoted by e) to hold the value of the initializer, as follows: [...]

The `const` in your example does not apply to `a`, why it can still be useful is demonstrated by the next example:

> ```
> int a = 1;
> const auto& [x] = std::make_tuple(a); // OK, not dangling
> auto&       [y] = std::make_tuple(a); // error, cannot bind auto& to rvalue std::tuple
> auto&&      [z] = std::make_tuple(a); // also OK
> ```

Answer (score 1):

The compiler deduces the type similar to the following

```
typedef int & Ref;
```

It is the element type of the `std::tuple` object.

If you will then write for example

```
int x = 0;
const Ref rx = x;
```

then the last declaration is equivalent to

```
int & const rx = x;
```

But opposite to pointers references may not be constant in this sense. So the qualifier const is just ignored and you have

```
int & rx = x;
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>

int main()
{
    int x = 0;

    std::tuple<int &> p( x );
    const auto [a] = p;
    std::cout << std::is_same_v<decltype( a ), int &> << '\n';

    std::tuple<int *> p1( &x );
    const auto [b] = p1;
    std::cout << std::is_same_v<decltype( b ), int * const> << '\n';
}
```

The program output is

```
1
1
```